# Grab input value and use as array with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var coptions = $(me).parents('tr').find('td.desCell > .coptions').val();
 var chosenOptions = [coptions];
```

Is what I have tried to do.

```
coptions contains:

'Black', 'White'
```

I need to wrap it in [], and make the javascript read it as an array, but doing [coptions] wont work?

Also tried `'[' + coptions + ']'` , but then it reads this as a string.

How can I do this? If not, any workaround/solution to make it work? Maybe mulitple .coptions inputs (hidden inputs) with each "Black" and another "White" and then loop through with js to add to an array? How would this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method.

```
var coptions = $(me).parents('tr').find('td.desCell > .coptions').map(function(){
                    return this.value
               }).get()
```

Comment: @Karem No `coptions` should be an array of values. if your selector is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming your selector is correct.

```
var chosenOptions = [];

$(this).parents('tr').find('td.desCell > .coptions').each(function(){
     chosenOptions.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would return an array:

```
coptions = coptions.split(",");
```